# How to use Eigen::Ref with pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, eigen3, pybind11

I'm using pybind to wrap C++ code.

Given the following function, which is originally part of a library and should not be modified:

```
void manipulate(Eigen::MatrixXd& data) {
    data = data*2;
}
```

Using pybind, I can wrap it as:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/eigen.h>
#include <Eigen/LU>
namespace py = pybind11;

void wrap1(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXd> data){
    Eigen::MatrixXd mData(data);
    manipulate(mData);
    data = mData;
}

PYBIND11_PLUGIN(cod) {
    pybind11::module m("cod", "auto-compiled c++ extension");
    m.def("wrap1", &wrap1);
    return m.ptr();
}
```

But this creates an unnecessary copy `mData`.

This fails to modify the data:

```
void wrap2(Eigen::MatrixXd& data){
    manipulate(data);
}
```

And this one fails fails to compile:

```
void wrap3(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXd> data){
    manipulate(data);
}
```

How can I avoid creating a copy of `data` likewise `wrap2`, `wrap3` or an equivalent of `std::swap`?

Comment: `ilcavio`, did you manage to solve this in a good way? :)

Answer (score 0):

> This fails to modify the data:
>
> ```
> void wrap2(Eigen::MatrixXd& data){
> ```

Yes, this won't modify the original numpy array because pybind must first *copy* it into a temporary Eigen matrix to call `wrap2`. From the [pybind Eigen docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/eigen.html):

> One major limitation of the above is that every data conversion implicitly involves a copy, which can be both expensive (for large matrices) and **disallows binding functions that change their (Matrix) arguments**. Pybind11 allows you to work around this by using Eigen’s Eigen::Ref class...

Therefore, we have to use `Eigen::Ref`.

> And this one fails fails to compile:
>
> ```
> void wrap3(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXd> data){
>     manipulate(data);
> }
> ```

The solution is to define a function that accepts an `Eigen::Ref`:

```
void manipulate(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXd> data) {
    data = data*2;
}
```

Another option is to make `manipulate` a function template. See Eigen's documentation on [Writing Functions Taking Eigen Types as Parameters](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html).

Comment: The problem is that `manipulate` is part of the library that I can't modify. Thanks for the answer

Comment: you can make a lambda function that wraps  manipulate  to take `Eigen::Ref`